# Автоматически посчитать сумму вводимых в N-число TextField чисел

Tags: ios, macos, swiftui

Стоит задача вывести на экран строки с результатами команд. В настройках будет задаваться количество игр (пока захрдкодил). Проблема автоматически посчитать сумму строки команды после редактирования TextField поля.

```
import SwiftUI
class Field: Identifiable, ObservableObject {
    let id: Int
    @State var value: String
    
    init(id: Int, value: String) {
        self.id = id
        self.value = value
    }
}

class FieldsTeam: Identifiable, ObservableObject {
    let id: Int
    @Published var name: String
    @Published var fields: [Field]
    
    init(id: Int, name: String, fields: [Field]) {
        self.id = id
        self.name = name
        self.fields = fields
    }
}

func createTeam(teams: Int, games: Int) -> [FieldsTeam] {
    var allTeams: [FieldsTeam] = []
   
    for team in 1...teams {
        
        var fields: [Field] = []
        for game in 1...games {
            let field = Field(id: game, value: "0")
            fields.append(field)
        }
        
        let teamOne = FieldsTeam(id: team, name: "Команда №\(team)", fields: fields)
        allTeams.append(teamOne)
    }
    return allTeams
}
```

ContentView

```
import SwiftUI
struct ContentView: View {
    var body: some View {
        let teams = createTeam(teams: 1, games: 8)
        VStack {
            ForEach (teams) {team in
                HStack {
                    ForEach (team.fields) {field in
                        SystemTextFieldView(field: field) 
                    }
                    SummaView(team: team)
                }
            }
            .frame(width: 1200, height: 100)
        }
        .frame(width: 1920, height: 1080)
    }
}
```

SystemTextFieldView

```
struct SystemTextFieldView: View {
    
    @ObservedObject var field: Field
    
    var body: some View {
        
        ZStack {
            RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 20)
                .stroke(Color.white, lineWidth: 4)
                .frame(width: 100, height: 70)
            
            TextField("0", text: $field.value)
                .font(.custom("Impact", size: 40, relativeTo: .callout))
                .textFieldStyle(PlainTextFieldStyle())
                .multilineTextAlignment(.center)
        }
    }
}
```

SummaView

```
import SwiftUI
struct SummaView: View {
   @ObservedObject var team: FieldsTeam
    var summa: Int {
        var sum = 0
        for one in team.fields {
            let value = Int(one.value)
            sum += value ?? 0
        }
        return sum
    }
    var body: some View {
            ZStack {
                RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 20)
                    .stroke(Color.white, lineWidth: 4)
                    .frame(width: 100, height: 70)
                    .shadow(color: .black, radius: 1, x: 1, y: 1)
                
                Text(summa.formatted())
                    .font(.custom("Impact", size: 40, relativeTo: .callout))
                    .shadow(color: .black, radius: 1, x: 2, y: 2)
            }
        }
    }
```